# Web Scraping - Logic in database?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm planning a quite big web scraper project (100+ sites, millions of entries). A few decisions have already been made, but one still stands out: **Where to put the scraping logic?**

The things we want to scrape are not too different from all the price/product comparison websites:

- a lot of attributes are the same, but there are different categories which have additional attributes. For example computer components: every part has a price and a name, but harddisks have harddisk specific information, CPUs CPU-specific things etc. There are probably gonna be ~5 different item categories.
- different vendor websites vary greatly.

That's how I planned to do it:
Use scrapy, define a few items, use class inherition where possible (e.g. websites using the same shop software) and basically write a little scraper for every site.

One coworker, however, suggested to put (most of) the scraping logic in the database. That way we wouldn't have to have something like:

```
price = html.css("table tr td ... #price")
```

in literally every file. Instead we have the attributed + a chain of neccesary commands stored in the database and run them dynamically.

Is there any big advantage or disadvantage of having this over 100+ small classes? Where could we run into problems?

Comment: *"That way we wouldn't have to have something like…"* – what's so terrible about that? In the end it depends on *how different* these sites are. Is the difference so minuscule that a single changed variable/value can encapsulate the difference? Does it make your application significantly simpler if you can store those values in a database and update them there, as opposed to writing them in source code? *Do* you need to **update** those values often, and changing the source code would be difficult? Are you sure you will never need to write more specialised code per site?

Comment: I don't know what's so terrible about it. Neither of us is the decision maker, as I stated above I would rather do it in code than in the database. As for your questions: We haven't checked all the websites yet, but from what I saw up until they are quite different, some also using JS or even more sophisticated stuff (Captchas). 
No, we probably hardly ever need to update those values (source code access is no problem either) and are not going to need more specialised code.

Comment: *"but from what I saw up until they are quite different"*, *"are not going to need more specialised code"* – those two statements seem quite contradictory. Anyway, a database is useful if you have one "template", be that code or HTML or whatever, in which there are just some changing values, and you will often update those values and/or need other querying capabilities or anything else a database is good at. … It doesn't sound like that fits your situation at all.

Comment: Oh, I guess I got the "specialized code" part wrong then. Yes, there is probably not much code that is actually **the same**. Only the XPath (or whatever) calls will be needed all of the time. We both don't know have much scraping experience, but from what I saw having an XPath for every site is not going to work. (Too many factors leading to a different DOM.) Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: In what comes to selectors it's usually best to do it domain-specific, meaning you could use something like https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis to push each spider and using a NoSQL db like MongoDB to solve the problem of the items being very different from domain to domain...